# Control Template - XAML WinRT Button Padding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have started with XAML as part of my freetime and now I have a problem with the padding of the standard button.
I have the following code for a grid which resides in another grid, so I have four grids inside my page and the problem is that the buttons are cut off and I am not able to change the width or the padding of the buttons.

```cs
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"/>
    <Button x:Name="Player2MinusButton" Content="-" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" ></Button>
    <Button x:Name="Player2PlusButton" Content="+" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="20" ></Button>
</Grid>
```

The problem is now, that the button is cut of as you could see in the screenshot here:

[image]

I have already tried to set a negative padding/margin and also to make a Custom Style:

```cs
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-10,0"/>
</Style>
```

Thanks for your hints and I hope I have nothing forgotten in my first question.
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a narrower than standard button set the Buttons' MinWidth property:

```
<Button x:Name="Player2PlusButton" Content="+" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="20" MinWidth=50 AutomationProperties.Name="Plus Button" ></Button>
```

If you copy the button template (right click on the button in the designer then select Edit Template... and follow the prompts) you'll find the following:

```
<x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinHeight">57.5</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinWidth">109</x:Double>
```

I assume you're running on the phone: the Windows Store Button template is different and doesn't set the minimums. Your buttons come out small there by default.

Comment: perfect, tried to edit the button template, and removed paddings, margins and every thing, but still couldn't get the button to be as minimum width as it could depending on the content, never thought the MinWidth property was the thing , thanks a lot :)